# Why does the text of Pitom Ketores tell me that one maneh was used per day plus 3 on Yom Kippur when the total weight was more than 368 maneh?

Tags: korbanos-ketores-prayers

Please help with my understanding of the ketores. I must be making an elementary mistake.

The recitation of the formulation of the incense [here](https://www.kipa.co.il/%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%93%D7%95%D7%A8-%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94/%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%98%D7%95%D7%9D-%D7%94%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA/) and in my siddur explains that

שְׁלשׁ מֵאוֹת וְשִׁשִּׁים וַחֲמִשָּׁה כְּמִנְיַן יְמוֹת הַחַמָּה, מָנֶה בְּכֹל יוֹם, מַחֲצִיתוֹ בָּבוֹקֶר וּמַחֲצִיתוֹ בָּעֶרֶב, וּשְׁלשָׁה מָנִים יְתֵרִים, שֶׁמֵּהֶם מַכְנִיס כֹּהֵן גָּדוֹל מְלֹא חָפְנָיו בְּיוֹם הַכִּפּוּרִים

“there were 368 maneh in it.” One maneh was used each day, half in the morning and half in the afternoon. Three maneh were for Yom Kippur. This was made up of 11 spices:

(א) הַצֳּרִי

(ב) וְהַצִּפֹּרֶן

(ג) הַחֶלְבְּנָה

(ד) וְהַלְּבוֹנָה, מִשְׁקַל שִׁבְעִים שִׁבְעִים מָנֶה,
making 280 maneh

(ה) מוֹר

(ו) וּקְצִיעָה

(ז) שִׁבֹּלֶת נֵרְדְּ

(ח) וְכַרְכֹּם, מִשְׁקַל שִׁשָּׁה עָשָׂר שִׁשָּׁה עָשָׂר מָנֶה,

64 maneh making a total of 344

(ט) הַקֹּשְׁטְ שְׁנֵים עָשָׂר,

total 356

(י) וְקִלּוּפָה שְׁלשָׁה,

total 359

(יא) וְקִנָּמוֹן תִּשְׁעָה.

Total 368 maneh.

In addition there were

בֹּרִית כַּרְשִׁינָה תִּשְׁעָה קַבִּין,

9 kav

יֵין קַפְרִיסִין סְאִין תְּלָת

3 seah

מֶלַח סְדוֹמִית רוֹבַע,

¼ kav of Sodom salt

מַעֲלֶה עָשָׁן, כָּל שֶׁהוּא.

There were 368 maneh of spices and then the additional amounts mentioned in the second paragraph.

It seems that the total weight was more than 368 maneh. So why does the text tell me that one maneh was used per day, 3 on Yom Kippur as if that accounts for it all?

Comment: How much more than 368 maneh was there? If it's 368.01 then I don't think you have such a good question. Your text says later on תָּנֵי בַּר קַפָּרָא אַחַת לְשִׁשִּׁים אוֹ לְשִׁבְעִים שָׁנָה הָיְתָה בָאָה שֶׁל שִׁירַיִם לַחֲצָאִין

Comment: This may be of interest: https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=53913&st=&pgnum=351

Answer (score 5):

The בורית כרשינה and יין קפריסין weren't ingredients of the ketores; they were used only to prepare one of its ingredients, the צפורן (by rubbing it with בורית כרשינה and soaking it in יין קפריסין).

As for the מלח סדומית, not everyone agrees that it went into the ketores either. Tosafos ([Kereisos 6a](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=35&daf=6&format=pdf) ד"ה מלח סדומית) says that it's part of the phrase ואם אין לו יין קפריסין: that in that case they'd take some חמר חורין עתיק, mix in the מלח סדומית, and soak the צפורן in that mixture. So according to that opinion, all that's left to consider is the מעלה עשן (and כפת הירדן according to R' Nosson), and those were just in minute amounts (כל שהוא).

Now, the Rambam ([Klei Hamikdash 2:3](https://beta.hebrewbooks.org/rambam.aspx?rid=7815&rtype=%D7%A6%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%AA%20%D7%94%D7%93%D7%A3)) disagrees with that, and says that the מלח סדומית was always added. But he first gives the total of 368 maneh and only then mentions the מלח סדומית and so forth, implying that this total is meant to refer only to the spices.

(And by the way, it's not that the entire 368 maneh was used up every year; in fact they had a surplus, which, as we say further along in Pitum Haketores, over time - 60 or 70 years - added up to half a year's supply. So all that means is that this would happen a bit more often according to the Rambam than according to Tosafos.)

Answer (score 0):

The [Eitz Yosef](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=57995&st=&pgnum=164&hilite=) comments on the non-spice ingredients of the ketores that they are not part of the 368 'monim' because they are not 'sammemonim' spices and are only there to improve the mixture.

Therefore the kohen had to take an amount which included 1/2 moneh of the spices morning and evening. This amount woud have been somewhat larger than the 1/2 moneh.

[image: from Siddur Otzar Tefillos p 148 commentary of Eitz Yosef]

Comment: Don't you want to crop this image?